# LWJGL Display.setWidth/Height?

Tags: java, lwjgl

Similar to what you can do with a Java's Canvas class, I am currently trying to write a method to set an LWJGL Display's maximum size. The only problem I have run into is that LWJGL's Display class doesn't have a setWidth or setHeight method, and I can't think of an way I could write my own. My first thought was to somehow get the instance of the JFrame that the window was using, but there's no method for this either so I feel like I am SOL. I also tried using DisplayMode and just resetting the size through that, but it closes the window and reopens it every time it resizes. I am trying to write a method that'd simply resize the window as if the user was dragging it to enlarge it. Does anybody know how I could/should go about doing this? Is it even possible to get this smooth max-size effect I am looking for, considering that the display doesn't even update until you let go after dragging/resizing it manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need more control over your window, you can try using an `AWT Frame` as a parent to an LWJGL `Canvas`. This would allow your code to take advantage of default window methods, including `setWidth()` and `setHeight()` found in the Java standard libraries, prevent and control window behavior, and add listeners to run code for certain events.

First, `import java.awt.*` and then set up code that looks something like this:

Create a `Frame` and `Canvas`:

```
Frame frame = new Frame("LWJGL Game Window");
frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
```

Add the `Canvas` to the `Frame`:

```
frame.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Setup LWJGL and apply it to the `Canvas`:

```
try {
    Display.setParent(canvas);

    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1024, 786));
    frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

    Display.create();

    while(!Display.isCloseRequested() && !closeRequested)
    {
        // main code or call to code goes here

        GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        Display.update();
    }

    Display.destroy();
    frame.dispose();
    System.exit(0);

} catch (LWJGLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Not sure how much you know about Java, but from here, you could add an `ActionListerner` or `ComponentListerner` that does something if the window is resized.

Also check out the LWJGL wiki for [AWT Frames](http://lwjgl.org/wiki/). This should, at least, help to point you in the right direction.